# d3.brush can't get the content

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I created a brushX that will be able to slide through a context graph and show the zoomed version of the scanned data on a bigger graph. I am aiming to do something similar to the example on this link: https://codepen.io/jahnreektor/pen/gaXQpz?editors=0010    . However even I tried everything I could not get the data. Please help i'm stuck. Here there is my latest version of the code:

```
var brush = d3.brushX()
    .extent([[0, 0], [visWidth, contextAreaHeight]])
    .on("brush", brushed);
    
var brushArea = contextVis.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x brush")
    .call(brush);

    
function brushed() { 
    xFocus.domain(brush.empty ? xContext.domain() : brush.extent());
    focusVis.select("line line-rain").attr("d", rainLine);
    focusVis.select("line line-temp").attr("d", tempLine);
    focusVis.select("x axis").call(xContext);
    return d3.brushSelection(this);
 
}
```

Comment: `brushed` should have an argument (selection): https://observablehq.com/@d3/focus-context

Comment: However in the link that I mentioned in my question brushed has no argument but it still works. What is the difference between them exactly? Also I prefer to handle without arguments.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand you correctly, but it seems you need selection data in your `brushed` callback. That data is supplied with an argument (that's what I see in the Observable's sample)... I suggest to go over the link I've sent and see how it works in details